# Contour irregular data within polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I need to create filled contour plots of sea surface temperature (SST) data within a polygon, however I am not sure the best way to do this. I have three 1D arrays containing data for X, Y, and SST which I plot using the following to create the attached plot:

```
p=PatchCollection(mypatches,color='none', alpha=1.0,edgecolor="purple",linewidth=2.0)
levels=np.arange(SST.min(),SST.max(),0.2)
datamap=mymap.scatter(x,y,c=SST, s=55, vmin=-2,vmax=3,alpha=1.0)
```

I would like to be able to plot these data as filled contours ([contourf](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) instead of scatter) that are constrained (clipped) within the polygon boundaries (the purple line). Suggestions for how to achieve this are greatly appreciated.

[image]

**Update:**
I had originally tried griddata, but could not get it to work properly. However, based on the answer provided by @eatHam I decided to try again. I could not get my scipy griddata to work as it kept hanging at the gridding when selecting method 'cubic', however when I switched to matplotlib.mlab.griddata and used 'linear' interpolation it worked. The suggestion for masking the boundaries provided a very coarse and not as exact solution as i would prefer.
[image: Image showing the solution using masked clipping]

I searched for options on how to clip contours in matplotlib and I found an answer by @pelson at this [link](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Clipping-a-plot-inside-a-polygon-td41950.html). I tried the suggested solution implied in: "The contour set itself does not have a set_clip_path method but you can iterate over each of the contour collections and set their respective clip paths". My new and final solution looks like this (see plot below):

```
  p=PatchCollection(mypatches,color='none', alpha=1.0,edgecolor="purple",linewidth=2.0)
  levels=np.arange(SST.min(),SST.max(),0.2)
  grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[x.min()-0.5*(x.min()):x.max()+0.5*(x.max()):200j,
                          y.min()-0.5*(y.min()):y.max()+0.5*(y.max()):200j]
  grid_z = griddata(x,y,SST,grid_x,grid_y)

  cs=mymap.contourf(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z)

  for poly in mypatches:
      for artist in ax.get_children():
          artist.set_clip_path(poly)

      ax.add_patch(poly)
  mymap.drawcountries()
  mymap.drawcoastlines()
  mymap.fillcontinents(color='lightgrey',lake_color='none')
  mymap.drawmapboundary(fill_color='none')
```

This solution could also be improved particularily in terms of extrapolating the extreme edges in the North. Suggestions for how to really 'fill-in' the full polygon are appreciated. I also would like to understand why mlab worked and scipy not.

[image: Final solution showing clipped contours using set_clip_path]

Comment: What interpolation methods have you tried?

Comment: the scipy and mlab version of `griddata` and different methods so that isn't surprising.  I think the issue with interpolating outside of the data you have is more of a fundamental problem and will involve questionable methods to get around ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would interpolate the data using [scipy.griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata). You can set the region outside of your area (mypatches) to `np.nan`. And then just use [pyplot.contour](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) to plot it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def sst_data(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

                         #replace with ...
x = np.random.rand(1000) #... your x
y = np.random.rand(1000) #... your y
sst = sst_data(x, y)     #... your sst

# interpolate to a grid
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j] 
grid_z = griddata((x,y), sst, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

# mask out the area outside of your region
nr, nc = grid_z.shape
grid_z[-nr//3:, -nc//3:] = np.nan

plt.contourf(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: Changed variable name in the plt.contourf() call (was ..(grid_z, grid_y, grid_z))

Comment: Your suggestion got me on the right track so I accepted your answer.